# Devise3 Rails4 - Update password from a child nested form, with current_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, passwords, nested-attributes

I try to update password of my Devise User model from my Setting model form. I can do that without asking the current_password but for security matters i want to do so with current_password.
the "update_with_password" method seems to be the solutionn but how can i use it in nested form without breaking all the rails logic?

I have my Devise User model which has_many Settings
I have my Setting model which belongs_to User and which accept_nested_attributes :user
I am in my Setting form and from here, i want to allow users to change their password. BUT, i want to obliged them to provide their current_password. As i am using @setting.update(params_attributes) in SettingController, rails doesn't know about current_password. But if i devide update i.e updating in one side my setting params and in the other side using update_with_password for my user params, all the rails logic with error messages etc are broken

Is there an easy and clean solution?